# inline PHP stopped working with if function and javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, inline-code

I've had a wordrpress site working for about 2 years using a pluggin called Inline PHP.  This is a shortened version that used to work:

```
<exec>
  $levels = array('Level 3','Level 1','Level 2');
  if (in_array("Level 3", $levels)) {
    echo "<script language=javascript>getlevel('http://www.my-site.com/my-training/level-3/')</script>";
  }
</exec>
```

This no longer works, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried each component individually:

```
<exec>
  $levels = array('Level 3','Level 1','Level 2');
  echo implode(' ', $levels);
</exec>
```

writes the correct array entries, and

```
<exec>
  $levels = array('Level 3','Level 1','Level 2');
  if (in_array("Level 3", $levels)) {
echo "yes";
</exec>
```

returns 'yes' (and no if I make the conditional fail), and finally:

```
<exec>
  echo "<script language=javascript>getlevel('http://www.my-site.com/my-training/level-3/')</script>";
</exec>
```

redirects to the level-3 page as expected..

The problem seems to be when I am nesting the javascript in the if conditional and it's just staying on that page - and not rendering anything on the page.

ANY help, would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When you view the actual page and view source do you see the expected output of <script language... ?

Comment: no, the expected output is actually a redirect to a different page on the site, so when I load the with the javascript nested in the if conditional it fails to run and so stays on the page.

Answer (score 0):

So, it successfully prints `<script language=javascript>getlevel('http://www.my-site.com/my-training/level-3/')</script>` to the screen but the page doesn't redirect as expected?

This seems to be a problem with the getlevel function. Press 12 and see if there are any console errors.

Comment: no..  when i test the script without the conditional, it successfully redirects as expected, but when it's nested in the conditional it does nothing.  the console doesn't call out any errors on getlevel function